# Remove buttons in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, jlabel

I have a java swing project that looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class DiceGameReplaceDice extends JFrame
{  
    private JFrame gameFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton diceArray[];
    private DiceListener diceListener = new DiceListener();
    private ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int NUM_DICE = 2;


    private String diceImages[] = {"./src/1.png", "./src/2.png", "./src/3.png",
            "./src/4.png", "./src/5.png", "./src/6.png"};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        new DiceGameReplaceDice();
    }

    public DiceGameReplaceDice()    
    {
        // Initialize the frame that holds the game
        gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        gameFrame.setLocation(300, 100); 
        gameFrame.setTitle("Dice Game");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add Panel
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Instantiate a ButtonListener
        buttonListener = new ButtonListener();


        // Add 1 Button and 1 Label to a newly created panel 
        // Add new panel to West 
        JButton buttonW1 = new JButton("Add Die");
        buttonW1.setName("W1");
        buttonW1.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        JPanel panelWest = new JPanel();
        panelWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelWest,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ));
        panelWest.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 122));  // set to blue
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panelWest.add(buttonW1);
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        mainPanel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);


        // Create and display center panel with dice
        displayCenterPanel();

        // Add mainPanel to frame and display the frame
        gameFrame.add(mainPanel);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private  void displayCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS ));
        centerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 122, 0));  // set to green
        centerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        diceArray = new JButton[NUM_DICE];

        // Add 2 Buttons to center panel with images of 2 random dice 
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_DICE; i++)
        {
            // Create dice button
            int dieNum = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
            diceArray[i] = new JButton(new ImageIcon(diceImages[dieNum-1]));
            diceArray[i].setName("Dice" + i); 
            diceArray[i].addActionListener(diceListener);

            // Add to center panel
            centerPanel.add(diceArray[i]);
            centerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        }

        mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add mainPanel to frame and display the frame
        gameFrame.add(mainPanel);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Implement an (inner) class that implements ActionListener
    class DiceListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            NUM_DICE -= 1;
            displayCenterPanel();
        }
    }

    // Implement an (inner) class that implements ActionListener
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String button = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getName();
            System.out.println("Button Pressed: " + button);
            if (button.equals("W1"))
                NUM_DICE ++;
            System.out.println(NUM_DICE);
            displayCenterPanel();
        }
    }
}
```

When Clicking the "Add Die" button, a die is added to the screen and is correctly formatted. However, when a die is pressed, and the NUM_DICE is decreased, clicking on the die button results in weird overlaps and "ghost buttons". How do you fix this?

Comment: a) Don't show "approximate" code - the bit you miss might be the important piece. b)Before calling `displayCenter()` "again" are you clearing all the existing children in the panel?

Comment: a) I am aware, but, as mentioned above I am writing this on my phone, so I don't have access to the full code currently. But in the vague possibilitY that I have made a very common/stupid mistake, I wanted to get this out there ASAP. b) No. How do you delete children?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix would be to remove the `centerPanel` prior to adding the new one. Add the line

```
mainPanel.remove(centerPanel);
```

as the first thing you do inside `displayCenterPanel`.

However, your way of manipulating the layout dynamically leaves a lot to be desired. Instead of creating a new panel each time, just modify the existing one:

```
public class DiceGame {

    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int numDice = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new DiceGame());
    }

    public DiceGame() {

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        gameFrame.setTitle("Dice Game");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton buttonW1 = new JButton("Add Die");
        buttonW1.addActionListener(e -> {
            numDice++;
            updateCenterPanel();
        });
        JPanel panelWest = new JPanel();
        panelWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelWest, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panelWest.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 122));
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panelWest.add(buttonW1);
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        centerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 122, 0));

        mainPanel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(centerPanel);

        gameFrame.add(mainPanel);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateCenterPanel() {

        centerPanel.removeAll();
        centerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        JButton[] diceArray = new JButton[numDice];

        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
            diceArray[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(6) + 1));
            diceArray[i].setName("Dice" + i);
            diceArray[i].addActionListener(e -> {
                numDice--;
                updateCenterPanel();
            });
            centerPanel.add(diceArray[i]);
            centerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        }
        centerPanel.revalidate();
        centerPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Revalidating and repainting is necessary after invalidating the component hierarchy.

**Notes:**

- Don't create fields when local variables will do.
- `NUM_DICE` is not `final`, so it should be named `numDice`.
- Calling `gameFrame.setVisible(true);` when it is already visible does nothing.
- When you have a working version of whatever it is you are doing, replace `setSize(...)` on the `JFrame` with `pack` and be sure to calculate the size of its children properly.